# Выбрать неповторяющиеся элементы из двух таблиц

Tags: phpmyadmin, php, mysql

Здравствуйте!

Давно делал парсер клиенту, сливал товары с донора. Спустя год потребовалось допарсить товары. Я составил опять полный список всего, что есть на сайте донора. Т.е. у меня 2 таблицы с одинаковыми полями в БД id, product_id, name теперь я хочу со старыми данными парсера и новыми. Теперь я хочу выбрать только то, что нового во второй таблице. product_id - это идентификатор товаров донора, собственно по ним я и думаю выполнить эту выборку. Не совсем пойму, как мне это делать, через LEFT JOIN или что-то ещё?

Comment: Где можно ознакомиться со структурой БД?

Comment: id - это ваш id, product_id - id товара, и name - имя товара, тоже походу от донора.
тут собственно всего 2 поля не ваших, по мне так сравнивать нужно 1, а по второму искать, например искать по product_id и сравнивать name

    select o.*, n.* 
    from oldTable o join newTable n on o.product_id = n.product_id
    where o.name not like n.name

возможен еще вариант, когда имена остались, а id изменились, но вероятность мала...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если product_id товаров в таблицах совпадают, то:

```
SELECT p.* 
FROM `{таблица новый товаров}` as p
WHERE p.product_id NOT IN (
   SELECT product_id
   FROM `{таблица старых товаров}`
)
```

Подставьте свои названия таблиц. В принципе, product_id можно заменить на название, артикул или любое уникальное поле для товара.

Comment: то что надо! Спасибо!